# What's biggest difference between 64bit file system and 32bit file system

Tags: filesystems

May I ask what is the biggest difference between 64bit file system and 32bit file system?
More available inodes? Bigger partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard-and-fast standard for exactly what bit size means for filesystems, but I usually see it refer to the data type that stores block addresses.  More bits translates to a larger maximum partition size and the ability to use bigger drives as a single filesystem.  It can sometimes also mean larger maximum file size or a larger number of files allowed per directory.

It's not directly analogous to [CPU bit size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing), and you'll find filesystems that are [48 bits](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto#Bigger_File_System_and_File_Sizes) and ones that are [128 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS).  The bit size of a particular filesystem is usually very low in importance as it doesn't give you any indication of how fast, resilient, or manageable a filesystem is.